# How to use gradle zip in local system without downloading when using gradle-wrapper

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to build a gradle project with gradle-wrapper (`gradlew`).

When I build with `./gradlew build`, it outputs text

> Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-bin.zip

And I already got *gradle-1.11-bin.zip* downloaded separately and I don't want to be downloading it again when I build.

So, where shall I put gradle-1.11-bin.zip in my project or system so that I don't have to download again?

*gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties* is as following.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-bin.zip
```

And I've tried copying *gradle-1.11-bin.zip* into *gradle/wrapper/dists* which didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

From [gradle-wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) documentation, I found in section *61.1. Configuration*

> If you don't want any download to happen when your project is build
> via gradlew, simply add the Gradle distribution zip to your version
> control at the location specified by your wrapper configuration. A
> relative URL is supported - you can specify a distribution file
> relative to the location of gradle-wrapper.properties file.

So, I changed `distributionUrl`  property in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=gradle-1.11-bin.zip
```

Then, I made a copy of `gradle-1.11-bin.zip` in `gradle/wrapper/`.

Then, `./gradlew build` downloaded local copy of zip and built the project.

---

Here's a real-world example:

```bash
mkdir -p $HOME/dev
cd $HOME/dev
git clone https://github.com/oss-review-toolkit/ort
cd ort/gradle/wrapper
wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
sed -i 's/distributionUrl=.*/distributionUrl=gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip/' gradle-wrapper.properties 
cd ../..
./gradlew installDist
```

Comment: This misses a main point of the wrapper, which is that Gradle is downloaded and installed automatically for all build users. If you prefer to use a local installation, put it on your PATH and invoke `gradle` rather than `gradlew`.

Comment: This is a big deal if you need to send software to somebody who doesn't have Internet access. Yes, that's something that really happens; there are computers that aren't connected to the Internet.

Comment: This is very important for Enterprise usage. Our build server is not allowed to access the internet. All dependencies are fetched from Nexus, but the wrapper always was a problem and stopped the adoption of gradle. A central installation could solve it but you would need all possible versions of gradle since every build could use it specific version. However the best solution would be to fetch the zip also from nexus, but this change request was refused.

Comment: Is there a way to use environment variables to define the gradle path that is located inside the Android Studio folder? for example define a relative path for: `..\android-studio\gradle\gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Comment: // Do not use android 8 as it will keep downloading grade distribution use grade 7
ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0

Comment: This was a life-saver. I kept getting SSL errors saying that the file couldn't be downloaded. This workaround let me complete my build. Thanks!

Answer (score 58):

Modifty the gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties

Windows:

```
distributionUrl=file\:/d:/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

linux:

```
distributionUrl=file\:/tmp/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Usually, I use the windows version of Android Studio but sometimes I open my projects in a Linux operating system. Is it possible to define `distributionUrl` in such a way that Gradle ZIP package be accessible on both OS without changing `distributionUrl` value?

Comment: @ir-tech, you can use relative path, like file\:///../lib/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Comment: // Do not use android 8 as it will keep downloading grade distribution use grade 7
ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0

// This will run
ionic cordova platform add android@~7.1.1 --save

Then  run below and this time it should get success( Worked for me)

ionic cordova build android

Comment: This did not work for me. Just omitting the 'file' stuff worked fine though: `distributionUrl=../lib/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip`. The path is relative to the `/gradle/wrapper/` folder.

Comment: Nice~ Saved my life.

Answer (score 28):

Just drag downloaded gradle file in your browser address bar and then copy address from address bar and change gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties as following:

```
distributionUrl=ADDRESS THAT COPY FROM YOUR BROWSER
```

example:

```
distributionUrl=file:///E:/gradle/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

---

or you can copy gradle.zip file to wrapper folder then use relative path:

```
distributionUrl=gradle.zip
```

Comment: Not working. distributionUrl get auto correct to https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip on ionic cordova build android

Answer (score 9):

This is what I did to avoid editing all gradle wrapper for current and future projects.

- Locate your `gradle-wrapper.properties` in your project folder (eg. `./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`)
- open the file with a text editor like Sublime Text to locate the `distributionUrl` line (eg. `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-bin.zip`

The gradle binary archive needed is `gradle-2.10-bin.zip`. Another version is `gradle-2.10-all.zip` that includes everything including source code and documentation.

**Please note each project ships with different versions of gradle distributions and you can change the version to the one you have (`gradle-x.xx-XXX.zip`) that include the binary. (eg. `gradle-2.11-bin.zip` | `gradle-2.11-all.zip` ).**

Execute `gradlew.bat` on window or `gradle` on linux to start the wrapper to build the project.

It will begin downloading the `gradle-2.10-bin.zip` to the `.gradle\wrapper\dists` in your home directory (eg.`C:\Users\Sojimaxi\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-bin`). This download happens just once for each specified gradle version.

If you already downloaded the archive before you can terminate the download using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Go into the gradle download location `C:\Users\Sojimaxi\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-all\78v82fsf226usgvgh7q2ptcvif` copy your own copy of `gradle-2.10-bin.zip` into that directory then delete the `gradle-2.10-all.zip.part` in that directory.

That's all. Go back to your project directory to execute `gradlew.bat` and it will use your local copy instead of downloading a new one.

Comment: checkout answer of @wcc526, it working fine & easier to implement.

Answer (score 4):

This solution didn't work for me but help me to get the right way so if you want install gradle offline follow these steps:

1- at your project under gradle directory open this file (gradle-wrapper.properties)

2- at last line you will find the gradle version, download that version or copy the file from another pc

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip
```

Download Link will be like this: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip

3- open this location 
C:\Users\userName.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all
and ensure that is only one folder (the name doesn’t matter it different at devices) if there any other folders delete all of them and press gradle sync on android studio which will generate another folder automatic with a random name.

4- open that folder and ensure that has only the last two files in the screenshot.

5- move the zip file that you downloaded into that folder

6- press sync gradle on android studio again suppose that gradle will work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found another easiest way to do this just started my XAMPP server and then made a folder `gradle` inside `htdocs`. I added the zipped file `gradle-4.4-all.zip` inside that folder. Changed the distribution url to `distributionUrl=http\://localhost/gradle/gradle-4.4-all.zip`
I restarted android and the syncing completed without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

copy your path wher you put the file **gradle-5.0-rc-5-bin.zip** 
example:
path **C:/My doc/tools**

*if you have some spaces in your path change it with %20*

**file:///C:/My%20doc/tools/gradle-5.0-rc-5-bin.zip**

and execute the command:

```
$ gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.0-rc-5
```

Answer (score 0):

I download to

```
C:\data\Setup\Development\Gradle 2.11\gradle-2.11-all.zip
```

inside Eclipse, I declare:
[image]

Then I create new Gradle project (with wrapper) very fast, no need download. (Easy more than this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22898473/3728901))

Comment: ya, it is speedy. beacuse unlike other answers, it uses the gradle available in the system than downloading a gradle distribution via http or file protocol, unzipping and executing it.

Comment: In my case, firstly i geos with @edward anderson's method. then switched to wcc526's method ( it is a modification of TheKojuEffect's method), atlast to this method.

Comment: But now i have a problem with this method. i am using gradle-4.0-rc-3 on my system. but that version deosn't work latest android studio ( i think latest version is 3.0-alpha6, but i have 3.0-alpha5) - it always errors by latest supported gradle version is gradle-4.0-milestone-1, your version is 4.0-rc-3. i have to downgrade my system gradle to 4.0-milestone-1 or always use gradle wrapper with android studio projects. is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Just making gradle work in your IDE but not the gradle command line is a great way to not be able to use or trust your build tool to do anything.  You should only try to make the IDE work _AFTER_ you verify the command line build is successful.  Doing it the other way around is a great way to lose hours and days of your lives trying to figure out why things break randomly and differently on yours and everyone else's machine...

Answer (score 0):

create local server to mock https download(maybe a little complex),but it work
1. [install tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) then unzip and exec `E:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\bin\startup.bat`

2.put `gradle-2.14.1-all.zip` to `E:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\webapps\ROOT\distributions`

3.change url like this `distributionUrl=http\://localhost:8080/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`
now run as usual

Comment: checkout answer of @wcc526, it working fine & easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

**// Do not use android 8 as it will keep downloading grade distribution use grade 7**

> ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0

**// This will run**

> ionic cordova platform add android@~7.1.1 --save

**Then  run below and this time it should get success( Worked for me)**

> ionic cordova build android