# create a gradle base android project offline

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I want to create a gradle base android project in JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2 .
i have gradle 2.2 in my computer and use it for my java project but when i create a gradle base android project , it start to download gradle 2.1 and when i disconnect internet give me error

> Error:Distribution download cancelled. Using distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'.

how can i set my local gradle 2.2 for this project??

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Do you have a gradle-wrapper.properties files?

Comment: yes , i have this file @cyroxis

Comment: Check your distributionUrl=

Comment: Relevent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896569/how-to-use-gradle-zip-in-local-system-without-downloading-when-using-gradle-wrap

Comment: thanks @cyroxis
i try to change "gradle-2.1-all.zip" with "gradle-2.2-all.zip" and open my project but it show this message
"version 0.14.2 of the android gradle plug-in requires gradle 2.1 or newer"
and when click ok , distributionUrl back to "gradle-2.1-all.zip"

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to gradle:1.0.0. You can change that in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file [name of your project]\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties change

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=[the location of your downloaded gradle file]
```

I hope it works.