# unable to install react-native project on emulator(Windows 7 )

Tags: android, react-native

I have installed Android studio 2.3, jdk8, python2, react-native-cli.
I followed all the installation steps.
Added **ANDROID_HOME** Environment variable pointing **C:\Users\pradeep.mandalapu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**  and added **platfrom tools** to path varible.
But i was unable to install the app on my simulator.
Can anyone helpme.
Thanks in Advance  .

Below is the error screen shot
[image]

Comment: Your Internet is too slow to connect to the Gradle server, try to setup  a proxy to download Gradle or use Gradle offline like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22898473/7987108)

Comment: I don't think My net connection is problem. It is fast.Problem is with proxy or some android sdk path